# two inputs on batch

Tags: batch-file, input

im working on this script for my work, but i cant get it to set a user name and password on input, any ideas.

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do ( 
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: computersystem get Name, Model, totalphysicalmemory /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: cpu get Name /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: path Win32_VideoController get Name /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: os get Caption /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: csproduct get identifyingnumber /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: memorychip get capacity /format:list
  )>"%%a.txt"
```

so i want the

```
 /user: %user%
 /password: %password%
```

how do i set that as an input?

Comment: I do not see any `SET` or `SET /P` statements in your code to create those variables.

Comment: the problem is that i dont understand it,

Comment: You are not being very clear.  Do you want to ask the user that is executing the batch file what the username and password is and assign those to variables?

Comment: Insert these lines before the FOR: `set "user=TheUserName"` & `set "password=thePassword"`; then, use your `/user: %user% ...` If you want to _read_ the values from the user, use `set /P "user=Enter user: "` instead

Comment: thanks ! i think i understand -.- but it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how you worded your question this should help.

I wrote this assuming that the snippet of code is **all** that is in the batch file.

```
@echo off
::put this above the start label 
goto input

::put this right above your for statement
:start

::be sure to edit the wmic lines like so:
:: /user:%name% /password:%password%
::also you may want to add something to check the inputs for
::any 'poison characters'

::gets input
:input
set /p name=Enter your user-name:
pause
cls
set /p password=Enter your password:
pause
cls
::takes execution back to the for statement
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:register
cls

echo account don't exist. please make an account
echo.
echo.
Set usrname=
set /p usrname=Username: 
Set passw=
set /p passw=Password: 
MKDIR "\path\"
echo %usrname%> \path\username.dll
echo %passw%> \path\password.dll
goto login


:login
cls
:begin
cls
echo  Please log in to your account!
set usr=
set /p usr=Username:
if {%usr%}=={} goto :begin
set authenticated=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (\path\username.dll) do (
    if {%%a}=={%usr%} set authenticated=true
)

if not defined authenticated (echo Invalid Username & goto :begin)

:passwo
set pass=
set /p pass=Enter your password: 
if {%pass%}=={} goto :begin
set authenticated=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (\path\.password.dll) do (
    if {%%a}=={%pass%} set authenticated=true
)
if not defined authenticated (echo Invalid password & goto :begin)

:loggedin
```